# Do the different personalities of Moon Knight have different religions in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, moon-knight

Marc Spector is Jewish in comics as well as in the new TV series. But Moon Knight has different personalities due to DID. Is there any personality of Moon Knight who is not Jewish by religion in the comics?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe so but also can't say for sure. To begin it's worth noting that Marc's multiple personalities actually started out as separate personas that he used to help fight crime. Steven helps finance the crime fighting and he uses Jake to gather intel. We see this in the first volume of *Moon Knight* and issue #1.

[image: Page showing Marc and his personas and how they make up Moon Knight]

As such it stands to reason that if they did have a religion (though I don't think it's known) it would be the same as Marc's because they started out *as* Marc acting.

Lastly, though I should note that Marc himself believes he set aside Judaism at one point in favour of following Khonshu as a God. He does seem to treat it as a religion and calls himself a priest several times too. We see him explaining this in issue #5 of the 2021 run of *Moon Knight*.

[image: Moon Knight explains giving up Judaism for Khonshu to a therapist]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>